# Intel Xeon E5- 2670 v2 Calculating GFlops

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance, ipc, intel, flops

How can i calculate GFlops for processor: Intel Xeon E5-2670 v2
Clock speed: 2.5 GHz
vCPU: 2
Memory: 7.5 GiB
Storage: 1 * 32 SSD
Networking Performance: Moderate(500 Mbps)

Its aws instance type: m3.large
I am not able to find IPC and calculate GFlops so i can estimate my cost.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xeon E5-xxxx v2 is an IvyBridge core, so it doesn't support FMA.  See [Agner Fog's microarch pdf](http://agner.org/optimize) for the details of the IvyBridge pipeline.

**If you manage to avoid any memory bottlenecks**, IvB can sustain a throughput of two AVX vector FP operations per clock.  Execution port 1 can run `vmulps` or `vaddps`, but execution port 0 can only run `vmulps`.

So: 2.5G clock/sec * 2 FP vectors / clock * 8 single-precision elements / vector

Thus: single-precision 40GFlop/sec theoretical max, using AVX 256b vectors.  double-precision: 20GFlop/sec (4 DP elements per 256b vector).

Note that even from L1 cache, IvB only has 128b load/store data paths, and can only sustain 2 loads and one store **per 2** clocks, for 256b vectors.

mul has 5c latency, add has 3c latency, so you need enough instruction-level parallelism to keep 5 or 10 multiplies in flight at once.

Comment: Can you explain me or give me a link on how you calculate IPC ?

Comment: @AnchalKhandelwal: I already did, in the first paragraph.  It's highly non-trivial for real code ([see some of my other SO answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+latency+throughput+uops)), but easy to give the theoretical max.  The vector FP mul and add units are fully pipelined, which I forgot to mention.

Comment: So to calculate GFlops, vCores could be directly used? What if my vCores is 32. This processor has 10 cores and 20 threads. Should i be doing : (2.5*10*8) * 2 processor ? cores details found at: http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Xeon/Intel-Xeon%20E5-2670%20v2.html

Comment: @AnchalKhandelwal: Like Agner Fog's microarch pdf explains, hyperthreading doesn't help *if* your code can already saturate the execution units of a core.  What it can help with is code that bottlenecks on cache misses or branch mispredicts, or on latency.  Unless you have very well-tuned code that can saturate a core without hyperthreading, you need to benchmark it on similar HW to see how it behaves.